# Can't edit DOM element by chrome extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for chrome, I need to insert my element inside another element. The first console.log outputs an HTML collection, but the second outputs an empty array. I tried to call priceBlock[0], but the result is null. I have a MutationObserver, with which I made sure that this element does not change.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const priceBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("price-block");
        const paragraph = document.createElement("p");
        console.log(priceBlock);
        console.log(Array.from(priceBlock), "arr");
        paragraph.textContent = "Your text";
        Array.from(priceBlock).forEach((element) => {
            element.appendChild(paragraph);
        });
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
        for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.target.classList.contains("price-block")) {
                const abobusElement = document.createElement("p");
                abobusElement.textContent = "Abobus";
                mutation.target.appendChild(abobusElement);
            }
        }
    });
    observer.observe(document.body, { subtree: true, childList: true });
```

I tried to ask chatGPT

Comment: Can you edit you question and add the HTML, which you are using? Also, what length does the HTML collection in the first console.log have?

Comment: Your observer doesn't look into nested elements, so it doesn't confirm anything. Look at console.log for Array.from(priceBlock) and you'll probably see it's an empty array. The most performant solution is to use a `css` content script with `.price-block::after { content: "your text" }` and no js is needed. If you want to use MutationObserver then you need to check the nested elements ([example](/a/39334319)).

Answer (score 0):

My MutationObserver was incorrectly written and therefore did not notice the change. Here is the correct option:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === "childList") {
            const addedNodes = mutation.addedNodes;
            for (let node of addedNodes) {
                if (node.classList && node.classList.contains("price-block")) {
                    const abobusElement = document.createElement("p");
                    abobusElement.textContent = "Abobus";
                    node.appendChild(abobusElement);
                    console.log("Элемент price-block появился в DOM");
                    observer.disconnect();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```